# Python Loop in File

Tags: python, loops

I have a script that I have written that downloads data, and sorts it out. It then needs to put that into a mysql database.

The Issue comes in when reading data from the file and inserting it into a dictionary. Instead of reading the first 12 lines, and entering them into the DB  (which is 12 column's Wide, so 1 line per Column)

It is looping though. So instead of a for each, I need to either read the data in groups of 12, and process. Or maybe there is another way I have not thought of that anyone could help me out with.

data.txt

```
A : 34
B : 234
C : DFG
D : SG
E : 452435
F : 4
G : 34554
H : foo
I : bar
J : 41234
K : lkjdfg
L : 134243
```

script

```
d = {}
with open("data.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        (key, val) = line.split(": ")
        Id[key.strip()] = val.strip()

        print(d.get("A"))
        print(d.get('B'))
        print(d.get('C'))
        print(d.get('D'))
        print(d.get('E'))
        print(d.get('F'))
        print(d.get('G'))
        print(d.get('H'))
        print(d.get('I'))
        print(d.get('J'))
        print(d.get('K'))
        print(d.get('L'))

params = d.get('A'), d.get('B'), d.get('C'), d.get('D'), d.get('E'), d.get('F'), d.get('G'), d.get('H'), d.get('I'), d.get('J'), d.get('K'), d.get('L')
```

I am new to python, and figuring it out as I go. So if this is something very obvious, please forgive me.

Comment: please edit your code

Comment: `d` is always an empty dictionary. You'll always get `None` returned since the keys are never defined. You never created `Id`, so that will cause a NameError. Probably this isn't quite the code you are running? Does your text file contain more than 12 lines?

Comment: yes it does, contains around 2200 lines

Answer (score 0):

use

```
params = d.values()
```

instead of

```
params = d.get('A'), d.get('B'), d.get('C'), d.get('D'), d.get('E'), d.get('F'), d.get('G'), d.get('H'), d.get('I'), d.get('J'), d.get('K'), d.get('L')
```

that will get you a list of values

```
['134243', '34554', '4', 'lkjdfg', '234', '452435', 'bar', 'SG', 'foo', 'DFG', '41234', '34']
```

also, there is no need for parens in (key, val) = split

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like...

```
def process(f):
    for i in range(0, len(f), 12):  # count by 12s
        params = f[0+i:12+i]
        # do something with params

with open("data.txt") as f:
    process(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

[`itertools` has a recipe for reading an iterable in chunks of fixed size](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes). And, good news, Python files are iterable.

```
import itertools

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return itertools.izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)


def chunkreader(f, n):
    chunks = grouper(f, n, "")
    for chunk in chunks:
        yield(line.strip() for line in chunk)


def process(chunk):
    d = {}
    for line in chunk:
        if line:
            k, v = line.split(":")
            d[k] = v
    insert_in_db(d)

def insert_in_db(d):
    # mock
    print d

with open("test.txt") as f:
    for chunk in chunkreader(f, 12):
        process(chunk)
```